# How to save a variable in javascript, so that its available in all firefox tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey-4

Im running two scripts using greasemonkey in mozilla firefox. The scripts run on different websites. In the first script i want to save a variable "globally" into firefox so i can use it in the second script on another website.

```
button.onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  //localStorage.setItem('savedvariable', document.URL)
  //window.name = document.URL;
  //sessionStorage.setItem('savedvariable', document.URL)
  //document.cookie = "savedvariable=" + document.URL;
}
```

All the options i tried didnt work, so looking for a workaround.

In the second script i wish to set a textbox value to the saved variable from the first script :

```
var TextBox = document.getElementById("downloadUrlLabel");
TextBox.value = "placeholder variable";
```

Is there a way to make something like this happen (saving a variable into firefox globally), without making it complicated?

PS : sorry if this has been answered before, tried looking for it but couldnt find it

Comment: `GM_setValue` / `GM_getValue` is the easiest option. You can also post messages with an iframe.

Comment: would that also work if the first script redirects the tab to the second page that has the second script? the second page isnt open at the time when i use the first one

Comment: That makes things even easier, use query parameters instead